# Bootstrap progressbar, show percentage text behind progress when filling up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap progressbar, where I show a certain percentage. Within the same progressbar, I also show the percentage in numbers.
When the percentage is low enough (until ~85%) the text fits next to it. When the it goes higher than that, the bar stops growing to have space for the text. See the screenshot (in here the top bar should be filled completely, but the text is blocking that)
[image: progress bars]

What I want is that the text is next to the bars, as it is now. But when the text has reached the right side, the bar should keep growing behind the text. So when the percentage is 95%, about half of the text's background is filled. At 100%, the entire progress bar is filled, with the text over it.

This is the code I have now for one bar:

```
<td class="occurrence fw-normal text-light small pe-4">
  <div class="progress d-flex">
    <div class="progress-bar occurrence" 
         role="progressbar" 
         aria-valuemin="0" 
         aria-valuemax="100" 
         aria-valuenow="100" 
         data-bs-toggle="tooltip" 
         data-bs-placement="top" 
         title="" 
         style="width: 100%;" 
         data-bs-original-title="Appears in 10 comments" 
         aria-label="Appears in 10 comments">
    </div>
    <span class="occurrence percentage mx-2 fw-bold">
      100&nbsp;%
    </span>
  </div>
</td>
```

I have tried playing with the position and display of both the progress bar and the text, but to no avail.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Could you please specified the version of bootstrap you use because bootstrap by default provide the functionality that you are looking for or you can refer the docs for same (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/progress/#labels)

Comment: It's bootstrap version 5.1.3

Comment: Bootstrap v5.1.3 also provide the functionality you were looking for (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/progress/#labels)

Comment: I don't see what I need. The text is inside the progress bar, but it doesn't answer any part of my question unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved only with JavaScript.

In order for label to appear in front of the progress bar, you need to set label's position to absolute.

Then, with JS get bar, label and its container, and get their widths for later.

Next, set width to bar, add label width to it, and check whether it's too large to fit the container, and if not, move it from the right by calculating gap, otherwise, it means it cannot fit, so move it to the right, and then it will show in front of the bar.

This is the key code:

```
if ((bar + label) < container) {

  labelEl.style.setProperty('right', `${container-(bar+label)}px`);

} else {

  labelEl.style.right = `0`;
}
```

Also, you'd need to animate label manually, so add bar's animation:

```
style="transition:right .6s ease;"
```

Here's a snippet for demonstration (it's buggy and hacky, but it should give a general idea on how it could be done, it will depend a lot on how you set width):

```js
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

    let iteration = 1;

    const interval = setInterval(function() {

      const barEl = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');

      barEl.style.setProperty('width', iteration * 5 + '%');

      const labelEl = document.querySelector('.progress-label');

      const container = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.progress')).width);

      let bar = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(barEl).width);


      const labelData = getComputedStyle(labelEl);
      
      // calc margins
      const labelMargins = parseFloat(labelData.marginLeft) + parseFloat(labelData.marginRight);

      const label = parseFloat(labelData.width) + labelMargins * 2;

      // check spacing, move label accordingly
      // else, fix to right
      if ((bar + label) < container) {

        labelEl.style.setProperty('right', `${container-(bar+label)}px`);

      } else {

        labelEl.style.right = `0`;
      }

      labelEl.textContent = iteration * 5 + '%';

      if (++iteration > 20) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }


    }, 300);


})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
<td class="occurrence fw-normal text-light small pe-4">
<div class="progress  position-relative">
    <div class="progress-bar occurrence"
         role="progressbar"
         aria-valuemin="0"
         aria-valuemax="100"
         aria-valuenow="100"
         data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
         data-bs-placement="top"
         title=""
 
         data-bs-original-title="Appears in 10 comments"
         aria-label="Appears in 10 comments">
    </div>
    <span class="occurrence percentage mx-2 fw-bold progress-label position-absolute" style="transition:right .6s ease;"></span>
  </div>
</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```